# Not properly fetching and connecting oracle-20c with php html

Tags: php, html, database, oracle

i uncommented oracle11g and added a new class of oracle20c in xampp and added oracle essential code in website and trying to fetch data from database. the problem is if i have 3 rows in database then it is showing 3 rows in website but not printing data. i have implemented different ways to fetch data but it is not fetching data from database.

A sample of connection with html and php is

````
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "system";
//$db_password = "12345"; change the dbname and password
//$dbname = "slayerdb";
$connec = oci_connect($username,$db_password,$dbname);
if(!$connec)
{
    echo "<script> alert('connected to Data Base')</script>";
}
else if ($connec)
{
    echo "connected to Data Base";
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    PHP ORACLE CONNECTION
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form class="box" action="testingoracle.php" method="POST">    
            <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value=" Submit">
            <table style="color: whitesmoke">
            <tr>
                <th> DNAME </th>
                <br>
                <?php   
                if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
                {
                   $qry = "select ename from emp";
                   $result = oci_parse($connec,$qry);
                   oci_execute($result);
                       while($allrow=oci_fetch_array($result))
                       {
                          echo "<tr>\n";
                          echo "<td>" .$allrow['name']. "</td>\n <br>";
                           echo "</tr>\n";
                        }      
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: What do you mean 'showing 3 rows in website'?  Have you committed the data?  Are you connecting to the same DB.  Add some error handling to your PHP code.

Comment: yes, i have manually added data in the database and tried to show it in page